# Как реализовать выполнение функции в боте python в определённое время

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я использую асинхронную библиотеку **aiogram** в боте, мне нужно реализовать функционал настройки выполнения определенной функции в определенное время каждый день. То есть чтобы человек указывал время начала и бот в это время запускал эту функцию. Нужно чтобы всё было асинхронно. Время запуска думаю сохранять в БД. Но как создать триггер для этого времени совершенно не могу понять.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону менеджеров очередей типа https://python-rq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Насчет асинхронности не уверен, но есть такой вариант:
Есть такая библиотека schedule

```
pip install schedule
```

Пример использования:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")


schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Где `"10:30"` пишете время, допустим получая его из БД.
Где указывается функция `job` пишете свою функцию

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ, уже сам разобрался. В вашем ответе библиотека schedule синхронная, а код у меня на асинхронном фрэймворке написан. Для асинхронного кода есть библиотека asyncscheduler.